# auto increment date+1 day using multiple insert row on database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010

I'm totally newbie from C# and I'm currently using VS 2013 and access database and i'm trying to insert multiple records but my problem is i want to insert the value of the date selected by datetime picker to insert and it is auto increment by a day..I tried to make the code based on what i learned..and it has a minor problem

in my database i want to insert 10 multiple records using for loop and what happens in my attempt was was this one

```
EID     date
---------------
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/9/14
```

What I want to happen was this:

```
EID     date
----------------
10175   10/9/14
10175   10/10/14
10175   10/11/14
10175   10/12/14
10175   10/13/14
10175   10/14/14
10175   10/15/14
10175   10/16/14
10175   10/17/14
10175   10/18/14
```

here's my code, by the way my EID is not the primary so I don't mind about duplicates

```
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

int ctr = 0;
int counter;
counter =int.Parse(TimeIntxt.Text);
String counter2;

for (ctr=0; ctr<10;ctr++ )
{
    counter++;
    counter2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString();

    command.CommandText = "insert into EmployeeData (EID,DateIn) values('" + counter + "','" + counter2 + "')";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

MessageBox.Show("Success");
connection.Close();
```

Comment: `counter2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(ctr + 1).ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of your code `counter2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1).ToString();` should be `counter2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(ctr + 1).ToString();`

Also - while in your case it is not very important, but it's better to use parameterized queries rather than build command via concatenation, this helps to prevent sql injection.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) for reference about command parameters and how to use them.